# Would @ A name point to nameserver IP or server IP?

Tags: domain-name-system

I'm using several services on one domain (tumblr, google apps) and a regular web host account.  Would you normally point the @ A name to the host's nameserver IP address, or the server IP address?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you mean by the "@ A name". If you mean the A record for your domain name, then it should normally be pointed at the server IP address. If you mean the MX record, then it should be pointed at whatever server you want to be handling email sent to your domain (and you should have at least a second one, pointing at a different server). None of your DNS records should normally point to the host's nameserver (unless it also happens to be an authoritative nameserver for your domain name, which would be bad practice).

Answer (score 1):

123-reg display @ in their DNS settings to mean no subdomain. You would point this to your hosts ip. normally with a second A record for the www subdomain.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, the `@` means the same as the zone name.

So, the answer is: the A record for the zone should be that of the (web-)server, not the DNS server.

Having an A record for the zone/domain (`@`) is what allows you to surf to "example.com" and not only "www.example.com".